# Example Security Giving Stock Dividends?

Tags: data, dividends

I'm looking for a security that has some stock dividends. Any suggestion?

There are plenty of websites explaining what is a stock dividend or plenty referencing companies with cash dividends but all I find are cash dividends securities.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_reinvestment_plan but are looking for something different? Although I don't personally object, some would say this belongs on money.stackexchange.com since it's not really a quant question.

Comment: Yes. I was just looking for a company that gave that (not that usual) in order to take more case into account in the algo. About money.stack... that's arguable I guess because the intent was more algorithmic and programming tan just money literate. Sometimes the line is pretty thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recent US-listed stocks that have had stock dividends include:

NYSE:TR ex-date 20160304 (3% stock dividend, plus also a cash dividend this day too)

NYSE:EEQ ex-date 20160203 (3.582842% stock dividend)

NASDAQ:SNFCA ex-date 20160113 (5% stock dividend).

A stock dividend is effectively a tiny stock split.  In the case of a 5% stock dividend, it's the same as a 105 for 100 stock split.

Source: Internal databases at Norgate Data.

Comment: Great thanks! But many providers are giving split adjusted prices and therefore (simple guess) do not include that kind of information which could lead to a wrong screening of the information from my side and the doc of my provider is really not that good therefore an example was needed. Also splits would affect everyone and stock dividends only affect those that held the stock before the exDate therefore I would not say that it's "like" a stock split, right?

Comment: Stock dividends are exactly like stock dividends... they both only affect shareholders who are holding on market close the day prior to the ex-date.  Stock splits/stock dividend have no effect on your shareholding if you bought on or after the ex-date.

Comment: Stock dividends are exactly like stock splits (*previous comment seemed to be politicians' language!)

Comment: Just to understand, TR for example, on morningstar there is no information about that. On Nasdaq there is just a cash div and yahoo reports a cash div and "stock split" YCharts reports like NYSE. Who's right in that kind of case? That's so weird! (like the political comment too)

Comment: To determine this you need to look at the company announcements.  In some cases, there is a choice between a cash dividend and a stock dividend, in which case the data vendor either tells you there is a choice, or they have a policy of using one or the other.  Finding the details of such a policy is difficult. Where both are received by the shareholder, they should both be present.